# I want the form to close when i click on the (X).

Tags: html

I added a form close button in my form but not working. Do i need java-script

```html
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="form" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="myDiv">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="form" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

<legend><img src="/static/images/premium/chat.png">......</legend>
<form action="https://chat.rbb.bg/ccp/chat/form/100000" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);">

<span class="box3">.......</span><input type="text" name="extensionField_PhoneNumber" id="box3"><br>
<span class="boxinfo">......</span>
<select name="extensionField_ccxqueuetag" id="boxinfo"><br>
 <option value="Chat_Csq23"></option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="........" id="boxbuton"><input type="hidden" name="author" value="Customer"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="ccx chat"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="extensionField_h_widgetName123456" value="........."><br>
<input type="hidden" name="extensionField_chatError" value="Sorry, the chat service is currently not available. Please try again later.">
</form>
</div>
<input id="info" type="button" onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden';" value="Имате Въпрос?" class="switchbuton">
```

to do the job.

Comment: *Do i need javascript* short answer yes

Comment: What do you mean by "close"?  What exactly do you want to have happen?

Comment: This is the code that i included :          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="form" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>.  I want the form to close when i click on the (X)

Comment: Have you tried hiding the form using Jquery? _.hide()_

Answer (score -1):

You may take help of jQuery in this case. I hope this demo is what you're looking for [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

You need to download and link jqueryui for this.

I hope this helps.